# How to get the geometry of Vector Tiles Protobuf integrated in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, leaflet-plugins

I use the Vector Grid plugin to integrate Vector Tiles (Protobuf format) in my Leaflet application. How can I access the geometry of a selected feature? I include the Vector Tiles as follows: `L.vectorGrid.protobuf('http://localhost:7800/mydata/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf', options)`

I register a selected feature by an on-click event. I tried to access coordinates by `event.latlng`, but it only gives me the coordinates of the point the user clicked. I want to get the original geometry of the polyline that is selected. Can that be achieved?

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is searching for this issue. I solved it by returning the geometry explicitly from the database so that it is included as property in the returning features.

Attention: the tile size increases dramatically! The size for my tiles was double!

Comment: But what about performance? Do you include complete geometry regardless of zoom?

Comment: No I already filter the data depending on the zoom level. For those features that are sent back to the client, I attach the geometry as additional attribute. I didn't notice any performance differences, and it is just one attribute more to the already 15 existing attributes.

Comment: Are you returning full geometry or some reduced one depending on zoom? If you always return full geometry, this defeats the purpose of vector tile layers which are primarily intended for huge vector layer with tens or even hundreds of MB of geometry data.

Comment: the geometry of the polylines is reduced by using the ST_AsMVTGeom() function. I additionally tried to simplify the geometry with ST_Simplify(), but this did not show any performance improvement.